# How to use backup semantics (seBackup privilege) over the network?

Tags: winapi, backup, remote-access, cifs, fileserver

I am trying to enumerate a directory on a remote file server.
I want to use backup-semantics in order to not require administrator credentials.

On the test server, I have created a share:

1. Share permissions: everyone full control
2. NTFS permissions: only SYSTEM (I removed all others)

I am currently using this code:

```
static void accessWithBackupSemantics() {

        NetResource netResource = new NetResource() {
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplayType.Share,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Connectable,
            RemoteName = @"\\target-srv\TargetShare"
        };

        // open "net use" connection
        int netResult = Native.WNetAddConnection2(netResource, 
                                                  @"***password***",
                                                  @"DOMAIN\backup_op_user", 
                                                  0);
        if (netResult == 0 || netResult == 1219) {

            // enable privileges 
            // (this is taken from AplhaFS)
            using (new PrivilegeEnabler(Privilege.Backup)) {

                try {

                    // try open remote directory
                    SafeFileHandle fsHandle = Native.CreateFile(
                        @"\\target-srv\TargetShare",
                        EFileAccess.GenericRead,
                        EFileShare.Read | EFileShare.Write,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting,
                        EFileAttributes.BackupSemantics,
                        IntPtr.Zero);

                    Console.WriteLine("Handle is valid: " + !fsHandle.IsInvalid);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {}
                finally {
                    Native.WNetCancelConnection2(netResource.RemoteName, 0, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- **PrivilegeEnabler** class is taken from [AlphaFS](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS)
- Native win32 structures and flags are taken from [pinvoke.net/kernel32.createfile](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createfile)

This works if I specify "DOMAIN\Administrator" in the username, but does not work (the error is 5 - access denied) if I try to use a domain account that is a member of the local "Backup Operators" on *target-srv* server.

I have also examined the security event log on *target-srv*, for every connection created with *WNetAddConnection2* a "Special Logon" event is written. The details of this event include the list of privileges that the logon account was given.
In both cases (when I connect with *administrator* or with *backup_op_user*) - *seBackupPrivilege* is indeed listed. 
I tried to give extra privileges to the "Backup Operators" so the list has all the privileges that the Administrator has - but it made no change.

Questions:

1. **What is the right way to use Backup-Semantics over the network?**
2. How come it works with Administrator and not with a member of "Backup Operators" - are there additional implicit permissions for the Admin?

I have seen many examples of local use of Backup-Semantics, but not one that can be used over the network - please don't reply with links to examples of local usage.

Comment: Is the machine joined to a domain?  If not, UAC will block all use of administrator privileges over the network, except for the built-in Administrator account.

Comment: I'll be surprised if this is possible.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Yes the machine is in a domain

Comment: @CareyGregory - How do Backup products work then? Do you claim a backup system always has a locally installed agent?
Plus: it does work for the Administrator - without the backupSemantics flag even the Administrator has no access.

Comment: I'm unaware of backup products that can do what you're talking about without a local agent and/or admin access rights.

Comment: @CareyGregory, backup privilege does work over the network, although IIRC you need to have it at both ends.  I have a few tools that depend on this, though I'm always using an administrator account rather than a Backup Operators account.  Roman, does it work if you configure the service to run as `backup_op_user` rather than explicitly specifying the credentials when you establish the network connection?  (You will need to make sure that the user is in Backup Operators on both the local and remote machines.)

Comment: Also, does it work if the credentials you specify when connecting are for a domain account that is in the local Administrators group on the target server but is not a domain administrator?